# Reset the time stamp to zero with CAPL

Tags: logging, reset, can-bus, capl, canoe

I am trying to automate with a CAPL for replaying different .asc files saved all of them in one specific path, I want to replay them one by one to generate new .asc log files but I would like to know if it is possible to reset to zero the timestamp in the new log file when I stop the first log and I start the following log, I mean, I would like to obtain all the new logs starting from timestamp zero but I don't know how I can do in the CAPL to reset the timestamp when I start a new log.

Comment: _Resetting_ CANoe's simulation time can only be done by stopping and re-starting the measurement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comments, there is no possibility of resetting simulation time in CANoe. However since .asc is not a binary log format, you could try to adjust the time by subtracting first event timestamp or some constant from all events in Python/etc.